# How can i use backbonejs with windows 8 store app?

Tags: windows, backbone.js, microsoft-metro

I want to use `Backbone.js` in `Windows 8 JavaScript Store App` is it possible ? if possible then give me idea how can i use ? and how can i manage `restful API` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decent article on it here - http://jrtipton.tumblr.com/post/28131822076/using-backbone-js-with-win8-metro-winjs .

Comment: i saw this article before. but author did not tell how can we embed and use. and how restful Api work with window 8 app.